# How to redirect an externally generated dynamic link

Tags: javascript, jquery, .htaccess, redirect, dynamic-linking

Some time ago I thought about how to reduce the costs of my webpage.
I decided to use an advertisement. It is a text-link-ad. When the text-link is clicked
the advertisement is opened in a new tab.

After some time I realised that is really boring to close the ad not just for me, but for all the people visiting my webpage.

The solution I came up with was to make a frame. I know frames suck, but it was the only solution I could think of.

It looks something like this:

```
<frameset rows="0.01%,99.99%" border="0" SCROLLING=NO NORESIZE>
<frame src="script" name="script">  
<frame src="advertisement.html" name="advertisement ">
</frameset>
```

In the script-frame I've put javascript which redirects the visitor back to my page when the mouse is clicked somewhere on/at/in(don't know which one it is :) ) the window.

So now to my problem:
I've got this generated link from sponsorad.de

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.sponsorads.de/script.php?s=209836"></script>
```

The script it is executing is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var preferrer='';`
try {
        preferrer = top.document.referrer;
    } catch (e) {
        preferrer = '';
    } finally {
        var rndVal = 100*(Math.random());
        document.write('<!-- '+rndVal+'-->');
        document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text\/javascript"
           src="http://www.sponsorads.de/a_script.php?s=209836&pref=' +
           escape(preferrer) +
           '&ref=' + 
           escape(document.referrer) + 
           '&ck=1&rndVal=' +
           rndVal +
           '"><\/scr' + 
           'ipt>'
         );
     }
</script>
```

So how can i make this link open in my advertisement-frame?
I'm open for a Javascript, jQuery, .htaccess or any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var preferrer='';`
  try {
    preferrer = top.document.referrer;
  } catch (e) {
    preferrer = '';
  } finally {
    var rndVal = 100*(Math.random());
    var txt = '<!-- '+rndVal+'-->';
    txt += '<script type="text\/javascript"
       src="http://www.sponsorads.de/a_script.php?s=209836&pref=' +
       escape(preferrer) +
       '&ref=' + 
       escape(document.referrer) + 
       '&ck=1&rndVal=' +
       rndVal +
       '"><\/script>';
    window.advertisement.document.write(txt);
    window.advertisement.document.close();
  }
</script>
```

or if you do not want to hack their script, do this:

```
<script>
var oldWrite = document.write;
document.write=function(str) {
  window.advertisement.document.write(str);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.sponsorads.de/script.php?s=209836"></script>
<script>
document.write=oldWrite;
window.advertisement.document.close();
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. After I used your script there was no link.

Comment: No. After I used your second script there was no link.